# Code that sorts a file into a list and then prints the values and separates into groups

Tags: python, list, function, integer, sequence

Need help with a code that reads a file and sorts the numbers into sequences as int values. I have been able to do the other functions but am having difficulty with the following function. I need to have it print the positive and negative values of a sequence...

`printIntegerSequenceInformation`: This function receives as a parameter the list (list of integers) with an integer sequence and does not return any value. The function prints the following information (you must use the output messages presented below):

```
Values: 1 3 5 7 9 11
num of Values: 6
num Positive Values: 6
num Negative Values: 0
```

Code:

```
def printIntegerSequenceInformation(ListOfSequences):
  p_count=0
  n_count=0
  i=0
  print("values:",end=" ")
  l = ListOfSequences
  while i<len(l):
    print(l[i],end=" ")
    if(l[i]>0):
      p_count+=1
    elif(l[i]<0):
      n_count+=1
    i+=1
  print("\n# of values:",len(ListOfSequences))
  print("# Positive values:",p_count)
  print("# Negative values:",n_count)
```

Here are my other functions for the program.

```
def readFromFile(filename):
  fh = open(filename)
  ListOfSequences = []
  for line in fh:
    if line[-1] == '\n':
      line = line[:-1]
    sequence = line.split(" ")
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
      sequence[i] = int(sequence[i])
    ListOfSequences.append(sequence)
  fh.close()
  return ListOfSequences

def printIntegerSequence(ListOfSequences):
  for no, sequence in enumerate(ListOfSequences, start=1):
    print(f"Sequence #{no}")
    sequence = list(map(str, sequence))
    print(" ".join(sequence))
```

Comment: What are you having issues with?

Comment: Please provide a complete (i.e. runnable) [mre].

Comment: the printintegersequence function is not returning anything